# Ember user authentication (Client side and Server Side completely separated)

Tags: ember.js, javascript, authentication

*I am completely new to ember.js.

I'm building a dashboard that requires an login (authentication page). I'd want to find a secure way to send credentials via an api call to the server side code, and I will be expecting a session token as a response, and I'd like to store that session token in a cookie.

I've looked into ember-auth, but I feel like it's for apps where the front end and the back end are in the same repo, but that's not my case.

What suggestions do you guys have?

My only restriction is that it has to be done in ember.js

Comment: check these out: http://www.embercasts.com/episodes/client-side-authentication-part-1 and http://www.embercasts.com/episodes/client-side-authentication-part-2

Answer (score 0):

Ember-auth isn't necessarily just for apps. You can configure the endpoints like `signInEndPoint` and `signOutEndPoint` to point to the urls that need to be hit on your server to do authentication.

Also there isn't any reason to bundle the client-side and server-side in the same repository here. The demo does this because the asset pipeline support in rails is very convenient for demoing, typically for avoiding a front-end build step.

You can treat it as just a [library file](https://raw.github.com/heartsentwined/ember-auth/master/dist/ember-auth.js) that you include alongside ember.

Comment: Thank you both for your comments, I found both of them insightful, however after doing a lot of research, I decided to go with ember-data's RESTAdapter.